# MySQL loop only can delete first data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have MySQL looping, when i click second button to get their id and do rest process it not working. why this happen?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#deleteSchedule").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_tna = "<?php echo $_SESSION['url_address'];?>mods/agent_management/code/";
    var deleteSchedule =$("#deleteSchedule").val(); //build a post data structure

    var JsonData = {deleteSchedule: deleteSchedule};  

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Post Get method
        url: url_tna+"email_template_response.php", //Where form data is sent on submission
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:JsonData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            window.location.reload(true); // reload before append
            $("#responds").append(response);
            document.getElementById("contentText").value = "";
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>



<?php $i=1; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

             <tr>

                <td><?php  echo $i; ?></td> 
                     <td><input type="textarea" id="TitleData" name="TitleData"  value="<?php echo $row['niceDate']; ?>" ></input></td> 
                     <td><button id="deleteSchedule" name="deleteSchedule" class="del_button" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><a href="#" style="display:block" class="button insertcolumn" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></button></td>
                    <? $i++;}?>
                </tr>   
        </table>
```

[image: only first button work]

Comment: **ID of an element must be unqiue** - the ID selector will return only the first element with the said id... that is why only the first element is working... use class instead of ID to group similar elements

Comment: you cannot have same id multiple times in a page.

Comment: you can add the `variable i to the id to make it unique

Comment: anyone have any example using class or variable i?.. i just want when click button got id and delete the data.. only first button can

Comment: how can we also know that your MySQL isn't also at fault?

Comment: my mysql work fine fred.. only how to retrieve the second button value

Comment: change `$("#deleteSchedule").` to `$(".del_button").` then `var deleteSchedule =$("#deleteSchedule").val();` to `var deleteSchedule =$(this).val();`

Comment: fair enough. well seeing you're using `mysql_` functions, I hope you're taking care of possible SQL injection also. It's easy for a hacker to delete an entire database in just a few strokes.

Comment: if the class `del_button` is used for other purposes also then add an additional class to the button like `<button name="deleteSchedule" class="del_button deleteSchedule"` then `$(".deleteSchedule").click(....)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny your solutions work.. you can asnwer my question for my review later.. thanks arun

Comment: @airi already somebody has posted it as an answer... so no need to post it again...

Comment: @ArunPJohny i just want to accept your answer.. if you dont want to post then i accept his answer then

Comment: @airi that will be just a duplicate answer... so go ahead and accept the existing one

Comment: @ArunPJohny i just want to ask one thing.. let say i want to edit second row.. why it get data from first column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91806/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-airi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `class` instead of `ID` in your script.

> In your Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".deleteSchedule").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url_tna = "<?php echo $_SESSION['url_address'];?>mods/agent_management/code/";
    var deleteSchedule =$(this).val(); //build a post data structure

    var JsonData = {deleteSchedule: deleteSchedule};  

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Post Get method
        url: url_tna+"email_template_response.php", //Where form data is sent on submission
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:JsonData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            window.location.reload(true); // reload before append
            $("#responds").append(response);
            document.getElementById("contentText").value = "";
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

> In your PHP:

```
<?php $i=1; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

             <tr>

                <td><?php  echo $i; ?></td> 
                     <td><input type="textarea" id="TitleData" name="TitleData"  value="<?php echo $row['niceDate']; ?>" ></input></td> 
                     <td><button name="deleteSchedule" class="del_button deleteSchedule" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><a href="#" style="display:block" class="button insertcolumn" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></button></td>
                    <? $i++;}?>
                </tr>   
        </table>
```